# HQL - conditional WHERE clause based on column

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm rather new to `HQL` and I'm trying to add a `WHERE` clause to my hql query in order to only apply a filter in case one of the columns has a certain value. I've read about the `CASE WHEN` statement and I'm trying to use it, but apparently I'm doing it wrong because I get a syntax error on the query.

What I've tried is the following:

```
FROM myClass WHERE CASE WHEN col1 = :val1 THEN dtIns >= :dt1 ELSE true END
```

Ideally, what I want to do is apply the filter `dtIns >= :dt1` only when `col1` has a certain value, otherwise I don't want to apply any filter.
The server responds with:

```
QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: >=
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to write query like this in your case:

```
FROM myClass WHERE col1 != :val1 OR dtIns >= :dt1
```

Is it solving your problem?

Comment: Yes, this works in the particular case I posted in my question. But can you tell me what I was doing wrong with the CASE statement? Can it be used at all in a WHERE clause, or do I need to rely entirely on boolean operators like AND and OR if I want to build a more complex case?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot use `CASE WHEN` in where clause.